# ValueError: The estimator KerasClassifier should be a classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a stacking ensemble using scikit-learn that contains a Keras model wrapped using KerasClassifier.

Here's an example of how my code looks using the iris dataset:

```
# import libraries 
import pandas
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense 
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import optimizers
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std

# import data
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("iris.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:,0:4].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,4]

# create and wrap neural network
def create_model():
    model = Sequential() 
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=X.shape[1:])) 
    model.add(Dense(150, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))) 
    model.add(Dropout(0.9)) 
    model.add(Dense(50, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))) 
    model.add(Dropout(0.9)) 
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
       optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=2e-3),
       metrics=['acc'])
    return model

model_nn = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=50, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
model_nn._estimator_type = "classifier"

# create stack
def stacking():
    level0 = list()
    level0.append(('lr', LogisticRegression(max_iter = 500000, C = .00041, solver = 'newton-cg', multi_class = 'ovr')))
    level0.append(('nn', model_nn))
    level0.append(('svm', SVC(C=1.0, gamma='scale', tol=.001, probability = True)))
    level1 = LogisticRegression()
    model = StackingClassifier(estimators=level0, final_estimator=level1, cv=5)
    return model

# evaluate model score
def evaluate_model(model, X, y):
    cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
    return scores

scores = evaluate_model(stacking(), X, Y)
print('%.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores), std(scores)))
```

and I get this error:

```
ValueError: The estimator KerasClassifier should be a classifier.
```

I found some posts where other users had this issue, but they were able to fix it using the `model_nn._estimator_type = "classifier"` line. Unfortunately, that isn't solving the issue for me. I'm really new to all of this, so any advice is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

`KerasClassifier` is migrated from `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn` to `scikeras.wrappers`.

You need to use below code to access the `KerasClassifier` :

```
!pip install scikeras
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
```

Please check [this](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/migration.html#changes-to-your-code) link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line `from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier`
to this -> `from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier`

Before that make sure you have scikit_learn installed

`pip install -U scikit-learn`  or

```
pip install scikit-learn
```